# TFS REST API to create a tfs groups ( NOT TEAMS) for TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I need help to get a curl **request URL** for **REST API for TFS** to create groups under team project. There is curl request for creating a team but I need it for creating a **TFS Group**.

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? You tagged this question with TFS2012, 2013, and VSTS.

Comment: How about create a app (e.g. web api, console app) to call tfssecurity.exe to create groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That REST API doesn't exist in TFS up until at least a very recent version (read 2018rc) and even then I'm not sure it's exposed yet. It's a [preview API on VSTS at the moment](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/graph/overview).

The old client object model, soap API is the way to go or using `tfssecurity.exe`.

Comment: Is there any API that can help me to add a user to this group.

Comment: The IidentityService will work just fine. It's part of the tfs client object model nuget package.